# How to animate colors of an image in android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-animation

I have an `ImageView` in Android which has a colorful image. How can I animate it infinitely so that it changes from color to black & white and vice-verse for infinity times?

Can I use XML or Java?

Comment: did you have frames to animate?

Comment: I don't have frames. Can I use xML?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying it's a good idea, but I make my buttons "animate" by making a button drawable with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/fb_login_button_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/fb_login_button_focused"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/fb_login_button_normal" />
</selector>
```

that of course reference other drawables.
this might be a starting point for you, just... don't assign any functions to the button being focused or clicked, but programmtically focus and unfocus it.
or see if there is some other state you can use....

gl!

Comment: I want it to animate infinitely... Color > Grayscale > Color. Thank you for the answer anyway :)

Comment: So loop your commands that change the state! This way you can also turn it off, restart it, and see what state it's in =]